# How to retrieve sub array elements when they fulfill the the condition and stop the loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

```
const winningTemplate = {
    firstRow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    secondRow: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    thirdRow: [10, 11, 13, 14],
    fourthRow: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    lastRow: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    firstDiagonal: [0, 6, 18, 24],
    firstColumn: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    secondColumn: [1, 6, 11, 16, 21],
    thirdColumn: [2, 7, 17, 22],
    fourthColumn: [3, 8, 13, 18, 23],
    lastColumn: [4, 9, 14, 19, 24],
    lastDiagonal: [4, 8, 16, 20],
  }
  export default winningTemplate;


    let checkTemplate = Object.values(winningTemplate)
    let isWinner = 0

    for (let checkWinner of checkTemplate) {
      for (let checkMatchedBird of checkWinner) {
        const newWinnerMatchedArray =
          updatedBirdClonePlayerOne[checkMatchedBird]

        console.log('newWinnerMatchedArray', newWinnerMatchedArray)
        if (newWinnerMatchedArray.includes('match')) {
          break
        }
        // setWinner('wins')
      }
      // break;
    }
```

I am expecting that any of the row column and diagonal elements are matched with using `includes('match')` then declare the winner.

every time the code executes the condition ('match') fulfills,and I see the array `newWinnerMatchedArray` has matched elements -which is going fine till now.

Now I want that anytime when 5 elements of any row or col or 4 elements of any diagonal array are matched we declare a winner and the loop stops. I hope it is cleared

Comment: please add missing variables with data. what result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can label the loop and break that specific loop:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

```
loop1:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for(x of something) {
    if (i === 1) {
      break loop1;
    }
  }
  str = str + i;
}
```

That being said I'd suggest simplifying your logic into pure functions and use the following:

- forEach
- map
- reduce
- some
- every

These methods are more explicit about intention per line, and make it easier to read and manage. You can still obtain optimum performance in the algorhithm if you use them cleverly.